# Generate JSON-patch from two objects

Tags: javascript, json, json-patch

Given two Javascript objects (`A` and `B`), is there a way to generate the [JSON patch](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6902), so that when that patch is applied to `A` it would change the object's properties to that of object `B`?

For example, given hypothetical `JSONPatch` function (perhaps being a function of similar name to one of those linked below), what is desired is the `generate_patch` function.

```
patch = generate_patch(A, B)
JSONPatch.apply(patch, A)  # modifies A so that it has the same properties as B.
```

In this question `A` and `B` are Javascript objects. A patch created by RFC6902 is JSON that would indicate an array of operations which when applied to `A` that object would become `B`. The `generate_patch` function need not return JSON though, rather for efficiency could return a Javascript object that becomes the RFC6902 JSON-patch document when `JSON.stringify` is called on it.

The projects I have found on the topic are:

- https://github.com/bruth/jsonpatch-js - only patches (does not generate a patch)
- http://jsonpatchjs.com/ - same
- https://github.com/Starcounter-Jack/Fast-JSON-Patch - observes an object, does not take two different objects

Comment: How does this differ from simply cloning object B?

Comment: Are you literally talking about JSON (e.g. a text string) or are you talking about turning one Javascript object into another.  Remember, JSON is a text format that can be parsed into an object.  So, I'm trying to figure out if you're trying to change one JSON string into the other or if you're trying to change one Javascript object into the other.

Comment: @MikeW - The patch is smaller and a string, suitable for the HTTP PATCH method, per RFC6902

Comment: Yeah, that helps a lot.  You should put that into your question.

Comment: Start here perhaps: https://www.npmjs.org/package/rfc6902

Comment: @jfriend00 Comment added to question - good call. Great link - checking it out.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Turning my comment into an answer...

This code https://www.npmjs.org/package/rfc6902 seems to be a full javascript implementation of both patch and diff for the stated RFC.

I haven't used it myself, but the documentation makes it look like what you asked for.

Answer (score 10):

Since version 0.3.9, https://github.com/Starcounter-Jack/Fast-JSON-Patch has a `compare` method which returns a difference between 2 objects. If I understand correctly, that may be what you were looking for

Answer (score 3):

I have also written a library to generate patches: https://github.com/gregsexton/json-patch-gen

I found out about 'rfc6902' after having written and used json-patch-gen. I'm not sure how they compare: it may be worth trying out both to see if one fits your needs better.